Accessing the scheduled time from within a Prefect flow run
I plan to run Prefect 2 flows on a cron schedule - but is there any way to access, at runtime, the timestamp at which this particular run was scheduled?
For example, if the flow is scheduled to run nightly at 2am, I want to use today's 2am timestamp to calculate the start and end boundaries for the data I need to retrieve and process in my run:

Scheduled time 15 May 2024, 02:00
Zero the hours to get the preceding midnight 15 May 2024, 00:00
Subtract 1 day to get the midnight before that 14 May 2024, 00:00
query the database for data between those two midnights
process exactly 1 day's worth of data

Importantly, if the flow fails and is retried at 3am or 4am, this clock time shift shouldn't affect the above calculation because it's the originally scheduled time that matters. We should still query for data between the previous midnights.
Basing these calculations on the current clock time, rather than the scheduled time, would work in simple cases, but runs into problems if the actual execution is delayed until substantially after the scheduled execution time, or we are doing backfill runs etc. Especially if running much more frequently than nightly, so retried runs could overlap with new runs.
But is that scheduled time accessible within the flow (as it is in similar engines such as Kestra, using execution.startTime)?
I have tried accessing the run context:
...
from prefect.context import get_run_context

@task(log_prints=True)
def do_stuff():
    ... do stuff ...
    task_run_context = get_run_context()
    task_run = task_run_context.task_run
    print(f"Expected start = {task_run.expected_start_time}")
    print(f"Actual start = {task_run.start_time}")


But the logged "expected start time" (for a cron schedule running every minute) is not an exact on-the-minute timestamp; when I introduced delays and retries it was sometimes offset by multiple seconds, so is clearly not the time scheduled by cron pattern, which should be precise on-the-minute.

The approach tried in the question, of using the task context, is almost correct.
The same function get_run_context() can be called within a function annotated as a top-level @flow rather than a @task, but here it returns a FlowRunContext rather than a TaskRunContext.
The attributes within these contexts relating to start time are named the same, but the expected_start_time in the FlowRunContext appears to be the scheduled start time of the Flow, and has an exact to-the-minute timestamp regardless of retries.
@flow(name="My Flow")
def my_flow():
    flow_run_context = get_run_context()
    flow_run = flow_run_context.flow_run
    expected_start = flow_run.expected_start_time
    # perform calculations, pass results to tasks as required, e.g.
    my_task(repo, expected_start)


However, one difficulty is that the expected_start_time is also populated for manual (non-scheduled) runs, whereas one might expect it to be None in this situation. Manual runs may therefore need additional parameters to indicate that there is no scheduled time, and to supply explicit time bounds rather than attempting to calculate them from the start time.
